# zero copy udp socket using sendfile instead of sendto

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm working with udp sockets in real time environment. I am currently using standard socket functions sendto() which takes relatively a lot of time. I read that it is possible to use zero copy, that, if I understand well, avoids having extra time added by copying files from user/kernel environment. However, I see that [sendfile()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) allows only to copy from one file descriptor to another. I can't see how I can use that to send UDP packets, which in my case is a buffer. So my question is:

1. is it even possible to use sendfile() to send UDP packets ?
2. If so,what is the correct way of doing this ?

**Edit**

I am working on a real time platform where I have several operations plus the sending over the socket. All of these should not take more than 1ms. I tried on three machines, the first has 4 cores at 3.4GHz, the other 8 cores at 2.3GHz and the last one 4 cores at 1.4GHz. On the first one it takes less than 1µs to send a 720 bytes packet. While on the two others it is between 6 and 9µs. I'm using a linux low latency kernel, and deactivated all CPU power management features, so all the CPUs are at max frequency.

I noticed that if the time taken by sendto() is larger than 6µs, the platform simply does not work. One other precision, I have several threads running in parallel. So maybe it is just the CPU processing other threads while the sendto() has not completed yet. I'm wondering it this is possible, to stop the sendto() while in process to do someting else.

This is why I was trying to find other solutions to do optimization somewhere else, and I thought that using sendfile() would avoid additional times to be saved.

Comment: In Linux (and the rest of the Unixy world) what *is* a "socket"? It is a *descriptor*. Just because some documentation says "file" descriptor doesn't mean it has to be an actual "file". Otherwise the whole `sendfile` call would be pretty much useless, if all it could do was copy files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Thank you. I am not so familiar with the difference between descriptor/pointer/... In my case I have a buffer containing my packet that I want to send. If I understand, it is not considered as the same as a descriptor, so it is not possible to pass it directly to sendfile(); right ?

Comment: No, `sendfile` only copies between descriptors. You can't use it if the source is a memory buffer. Then you have to use `sendto`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Thank you. Is there another way of minimizing the time taken by socket sendto ?

Comment: Reading the documentation link you provided for `sendfile()` I doubt that it would work reliably on UDP if it works at all. There  is mention of TCP which is a connection oriented, stream while UDP is a connectionless, packet protocol. So TCP has semantics that are somewhat like a sequential file while UDP does not.

Comment: I am curious how you are using `sendto()` and what is meant by "relatively a lot of time".

Comment: If you have real time requirement, you need a real time OS. Linux makes no guarantee on the time that an action will require because it can depends on plenty of other factors.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if `sendfile` works with UDP sockets, however, [`memfd_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) creates a file descriptor from memory and theoretically could allow bypassing the copying from the user space to the kernel.

Still though, when sending the kernel has to copy the data into the kernel socket buffer first because it needs to prepend user data with UDP, IP and Ethernet headers, which cannot be done in-place. This copying cannot be avoided even when using `sendfile`.

To do real zero-copy networking you may like to have a look at [PF_RING ZC (Zero Copy)](http://www.ntop.org/products/packet-capture/pf_ring/pf_ring-zc-zero-copy/) drivers:

> **On-Demand Kernel Bypass with PF_RING Aware Drivers**
>
> PF_RING™ ZC comes with a new generation of PF_RING™ aware drivers that can be used both in kernel or bypass mode. Once installed, the drivers operate as standard Linux drivers where you can do normal networking (e.g. ping or SSH). When used from PF_RING™ they are quicker than vanilla drivers, as they interact directly with it. If you open a device using a PF_RING-aware driver in zero copy (e.g. pfcount -i zc:eth1) the device becomes unavailable to standard networking as it is accessed in zero-copy through kernel bypass, as happened with the predecessor DNA. Once the application accessing the device is closed, standard networking activities can take place again.